# Nginx can't get client IP, it only return my gateway IP

Tags: nginx

My website is running by LAMP and proxy by nginx, I want only allow intranet IP, so I have set the below restrictions.

allow 172.16.0.0/16;
deny all;

it doesn't work, then I found all incoming IPs only show my gateway IP(172.16.0.254) in the logs like this

```
172.16.0.254 - - [11/Sep/2022:23:35:44 +0800] "GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 4768..................
```

How can I get the real client IP, not my gateway IP?

Comment: If your gateway sets a header containing the real client IP, you can tell Nginx to [use that instead](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_realip_module.html).